# How to create a d-pad with buttons in single view application on xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, d-pad

I have looked and found the code to make an d-pad with buttons but you would have to constantly tap the button to make it work. So if you wanted to go up you had to press up constantly. How do i make the object move with the user keeping the button pressed.
this is the code for the buttons i have already

```
-(IBAction)moveLeft:(id)sender{
Robot.center = CGPointMake(Robot.center.x-10, Robot.center.y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    Robot.center = CGPointMake(Robot.center.x, Robot.center.y+10);
}];
}

-(IBAction)moveRight:(id)sender{
Robot.center = CGPointMake(Robot.center.x+10, Robot.center.y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    Robot.center = CGPointMake(Robot.center.x, Robot.center.y+10);
}];
}

-(IBAction)moveUp:(id)sender{
Robot.center = CGPointMake(Robot.center.x, Robot.center.y-10);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    Robot.center = CGPointMake(Robot.center.x, Robot.center.y+10);
 }];
}

-(IBAction)moveDown:(id)sender{
Robot.center = CGPointMake(Robot.center.x, Robot.center.y+10);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    Robot.center = CGPointMake(Robot.center.x, Robot.center.y+10);
}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UIControlEventTouchDown` control event to start the method running, and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, or similar, to detect when the button is no longer being "pressed".

Set up the actions to the button, e.g.:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startButtonTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(endButtonTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

(Note the above will cause touch up inside and outside the button to invoke the endButtonTouch: method.)

Then add the startButtonTouch: and endButtonTouch methods, e.g., :

```
- (void)startButtonTouch:(id)sender {
    // start the process running...
}

- (void)endButtonTouch:(id)sender {
// stop the running process...
}
```

If you want to end it when the user drags outside the button, add `UIControlEventTouchDragExit` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the button up down states:

```
- (IBAction)touchUpIn_btnUp:(id)sender {
    self.buttonUpIsDown = NO;
}
- (IBAction)touchDownIn_btnUp:(id)sender {
    self.buttonUpIsDown = YES;
}
- (IBAction)touchUpIn_btnLeft:(id)sender {
    self.buttonLeftIsDown = NO;
}
- (IBAction)touchDownIn_btnLeft:(id)sender {
    self.buttonLeftIsDown = YES;
}
- (IBAction)touchUpIn_btnRight:(id)sender {
    self.buttonRightIsDown = NO;
}
- (IBAction)touchDownIn_btnRight:(id)sender {
    self.buttonRightIsDown = YES;
}
- (IBAction)touchUpIn_btnDown:(id)sender {
    self.buttonDownIsDown = NO;
}
- (IBAction)touchDownIn_btnDown:(id)sender {
    self.buttonDownIsDown = YES;
}
```

Check the states in a loop

```
- (void) updateControls {

    if (self.buttonUpIsDown) {
        // move up
    }
    if (self.buttonDownIsDown) {
        // move down
    }
    if (self.buttonLeftIsDown) {
        // move left
    }
    if (self.buttonRightIsDown) {
        // move right
    }
}
```

Call the loop with:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:MAIN_LOOP_TIME target:self selector:@selector(updateControls) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```